How can I choose a color scheme to represent the seven HSK levels, that contrasts well on a black background with black font?







HSK Standard Course textbook front covers for levels 1 through 6

In the Chinese-language-learning community, these colors are established as representing HSK (a popular Chinese exam) levels 1 through 6.  Nowadays, there's a new level 7-9 (merging levels 7, 8, and 9) which doesn't have a color just yet.
I used Pinta to identify the colors in these images, and obtain:

#F9A94A #3999A7 #ED6E07 #B81D25 #253E77 #673568

I'd like this to form the basis of a color scheme.  And I'll have to choose a new color for level 7-9.  I intend to use this color scheme in my talk slides with a black background image.  Here's what it currently looks like:



Some of the colors are too dark, and it's hard to read the characters.  And I don't know if I made a good choice for the 7th color.  I tried tweaking the colors manually, and it looks a bit better, but my changes seem arbitrary and don't seem to match the original color scheme.
Question: How can I choose a color scheme to represent the seven HSK levels, that contrasts well on a black background with black font?
Perhaps there's some kind of software out there that could help me balance these colors out.

Hi. I wouldn't use a black font with the red, dark blue and purple boxes. There isn't enough contrast for good readability.   Either change the font colour, or the box colours.

It seems important the colors maintain being recognizable. The light and dark blue colors make it hard to change the colors too much– otherwise they will look too similar.
A couple different suggestions / ideas:
Increase the thickness of the black characters so they can be seen more easily.
Add a thin white border around the black of the character strokes so they stand out more on the different backgrounds.
Place the characters inside a light colored box surrounded by the colored box so the color can be recognized and the character can be seen and read.

